# Binary Rejected for importing the Health kit but not implementing/using that

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store, appstore-approval, healthkit

As I have submitted my first app on App Store but I got rejection with given reason-

> 27.6 Details
>
> Your app also uses the HealthKit APIs but does not indicate integration with the Health app in your Application Description and clearly identify the HealthKit functionality in your app’s UI, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

I have implementing this feature for the next version so I am not using this framework anywhere in my project. Because of this I have also disable **HealthKit capability Off** from project setting like here [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h7a2.png) But they still rejecting the app. Do I have to submit again new binary or is there is way to continue with this?

Comment: Did you archive after disabling the HealthKit all over again or you are using the same archive?

Comment: @AdeelMiraj Yes, i archived after disabling the HealthKit

Comment: Remove the HealthKit framework from Build Phases->Link Libraries as well. Then create a new binary and try submitting your app again.

Comment: @JackChoin i am also having the same issue, did you find the solution i have removed all HealthKit Linkage but they are still rejecting myapp.which is the last step you have did ?

Answer (score 1):

disable the capability and don't link to the framework

a new binary is needed for sure to reflect both changes